# Java JMS = HornetQ = javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: Unable to validate user: null?

Tags: java, hornetq

I am trying for several hours to get the HornetQ Examples running in Eclipse. Using the Standalone Examples everything works fine, but when I run the examples in Eclipse I get the following error:

```
javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: Unable to validate user: null
```

What could this error mean? Where do I have to specify the user? Maybe HornetQ tries to look this user up in "Some Context/Properties" etc , but I do not know where and how to specifiy the user HornetQ is running under.

What i did:

1.)Started Default HornetQ Server with the start.sh Script in the ./bin directory

2.)Copied the QueueExample over to eclpise

3.)Did some minor changes in the config files (to have the same Queue Names...)

(I also tried to disable security completely by setting:

```
 <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
```

but with no success, always getting the same error. Also when trying to programmatically instance HornetQ only via classes I get this error too).

Thank you very much!!
Jens

Comment: Just a Quick note: It seemed that some of the "Server Threads" I started in Eclipse (when programatically instanciating HornetQ) did not end properly (Deamon Processe?) and after discovering them and killing them and running everything from scratch it finally worked.

Comment: Please rename this question to indicate that this was an Eclipse problem. Neither this question or the answer/notes is helpful for the greater issue outside Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at [this thread](http://community.jboss.org/thread/145854)? It seems you need to the permission  'createTempQueue' to the example role.

Comment: Hello extraneon, Thank you very much for your help. Well sometimes programming can be really daunting. Some deamon processes seemed to be not correctly shut down and after killing them everything worked. (I discovered them only by fortune, and spent hours trying to get this working... Thanks for your help!!)

Comment: @jens Been there, done that. Happens to all of us at one time or another :)